# How remove node from orginal list recursively with javascript?

Tags: javascript, tree

How I can delete child by id recursively of original list, im trying by every children,but this will not be practical when the tree is bigger .

```js
var tree = {
  name: 'user1',
  id: 1,
  children: [
    {
      name: 'user2',
      id: 2,
      children: []
    },
    {
      name: 'user3',
      id: 3,
      children: [
         {
          name: 'user4',
          id: 4,
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
tree.children[1].children.splice(0, 1);

console.log('tree',tree);
```

Comment: What should happen when id=1?

Comment: remove all include childs

Comment: So then the object with id=1 will still remain present, right? Which is different behaviour than when id=2... It would be more consistent if your tree were an *array*, and then for id=1, the array would be emptied...

Comment: Yes it is ,object empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach with `id` and a short circuit on find.

```js
const
    remove = (tree, id) => {
        let index;
        tree.children.some((o, i) => {
            if (o.id === id) {
                index = i;
                return true;
            }
            return remove(o, id);
        });
        if (index !== undefined) {
            tree.children.splice(index, 1);
            return true;
        }
    },
    tree = { name: 'user1', id: 1, children: [{ name: 'user2', id: 2, children: [] }, { name: 'user3', id: 3, children: [{ name: 'user4', id: 4, children: [] }] }] };

console.log(tree);
remove(tree, 4);
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: how can remove when id=1?

Comment: this is not possible, because of the object.